# How can I solve turtle addshape error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I try to solve error for this code. I'm using mac os
file is in right directory and use gif file.
but I kept getting error. How can I solve this(please help me)

```
import turtle
import random

screen=turtle.Screen()
image1="/Users/jameslee/Downloads/front.gif"
image2="/Users/jameslee/Downloads/back.gif"
screen.addshape(image1)
screen.addshape(image2)

t1=turtle.Turtle()
coin=random.randint(0, 1)
if coin==0:
    t1.shape(image1)
    t1.stamp()
else :
    t1.shape(image2)
    t1.stamp()
```

[image]

Comment: This does not have **anything at all** to do with C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.  I've simplified it below for my testing purposes.  The next issue is the *.gif files themselves.  Either they are variants of GIF that tkinter doesn't recognize, or they aren't GIF files (e.g. something else renamed with a *.gif extension.)  Since you say you're on Mac OSX, we can test this.  Run /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app, `cd` to the directory in question and run the Unix `file` command:

```
> cd /Users/jameslee/Downloads
> file front.gif
front.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 50 x 50
>
```

Your output should be similar -- let us know what you get.  Your code simplified:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

image1 = "/Users/jameslee/Downloads/front.gif"
image2 = "/Users/jameslee/Downloads/back.gif"

screen = Screen()
screen.addshape(image1)
screen.addshape(image2)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape(choice([image1, image2]))
turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! The reason was the file which I change to gif isn't proper file. I've never thoght about the case that the file was wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HtspgL, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)